# Reading folder containing a number of images on front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I have products containing multiple images inside public folder. The folder names are the product names.

```
public
--product_1
--product_2
...
--product_n
```

Inside each folder are a number of images, not necessarily of equal numbers, with file names `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, and so on (literally the filenames of images are just a sequence of numbers).

So, I am having this custom `ProductCarousel` component (a wrapper to Carousel component from some existing library) actually where I want to pass each folder's name as property from `App` (or any parent component) and this component will simply iterate through the images where they will be displayed in the carousel.

```
class ProductCarousel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            productFolder: this.props.productFolder
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                { /* I'm doing a pseudo-code here somewhat, just correct me */ }
                {this.imagesInProductFolder.map(image =>
                        <div key={`${this.state.productFolder} + '_' + image`} >
                            <img alt={`${this.state.productFolder} + '_' + image`} src={`${this.state.productFolder} + '/' + image`} />
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}
```

My question:

1. Can this be done in plain JavaScript?
2. If using plain JavaScript is too difficult (or impossible) or has too many lines of code, is there a React library to use that resolves in a simpler way ?
3. If the answer to the above are negative, is it necessary to use a server-side language like NodeJS (my last resort, I guess its "bad" to mix server-side and client-side)?

Any example how-to code will be appreciated for any of the three.

Comment: If the images are named with a predictable, repeatable algorithm that you can replicate in code, then you can set the source of the images to those files, following that algorithm without the need of a server-side language or additional libraries. This question, however, has too many questions in it, some of which are off topic (asking for a library, asking for "better" without defining an objective measure for "better").

Comment: Well, maybe just an example for what would be commonly used for such case, barring judgement on anyone's opinion, as long as working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how your images are named (the algorithm used to name them, unless they are truly named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., 10.jpg, ..., 100.jpg, etc.) and remove the extra questions and I'm sure someone can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it can be done.
adding `componentdidmount` and `tryRequire` function will solve the problem.

In `componentdidmount` we will iterate in each folder and importing images and save them in the state.
`tryRequire` function checks if the specific image exist on that folder or not. If the result is false, it will interrupt the iteration in `componentdidmount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    let i = 1;
    const pathName = this.props.fileName;

    while (this.tryRequire(`./images/${pathName}/${i}.jpg`)) {
      import(`./images/${pathName}/${i}.jpg`).then(image => {
        this.setState({ images: [...this.state.images, image.default] });
      });
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
  tryRequire(path) {
    try {
      return require(`${path}`);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**Update**

Actually this method will work if you save images in the same folder or sub-folder as component.

Comment: Is tryRequire a standard component method in react? I've never heard about it. Can you provide a link to the documentation of this method?

Comment: tryRequire is name of a function that I wrote, and please also see the updates.

Comment: I had same problem few months ago and solved it with this method. So it's not kind of documented method.

Comment: @oikonomiyaki , Does it help you?